# unable to update datetime field, value becomes 0000:00:00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql

what is it that im doing wrong that datetime field is not getting updated and instead the value becomes all 0

```
echo print_r($_POST);;
$time_in = $_POST['time_in'];
$time_out = $_POST['time_out'];

$id = $_GET['id'];

echo $sql = "UPDATE hours SET time_in = '".$time_in."' AND time_out = '".$time_out."' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: you have to pass date in below format (YYYY-mm-dd).

Comment: Format must be incorrect

Comment: So what are the values of `time_in` and `time_out`? And are they in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS` format?.... Debugging 101

Comment: what are the values of $time_in and $timeout?

Comment: Show your $_POST['time_in'] and $_POST['time_out'] result.

Comment: in form input field i display the current value and then on it i try to update but it becoms all 0

Comment: Array ( [time_in] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [time_out] => 2016-08-01 04:46:13 [submit] => Edit ) 1

Comment: when i first enter submit it shows the value but when page is reloaded the results bevomes all 0 and also update for time_out is not taking any affect

Comment: AND is incorrect syntax in this context. It won't produce an error, but it's in effect saying 'SET time_in = 0'

Comment: @Strawberry you are right it was AND causing the error. thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use following code

```
echo print_r($_POST);;
$time_in = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['time_in']));
$time_out = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['time_out']));

$id = $_GET['id'];

echo $sql = "UPDATE hours SET time_in = '".$time_in."', time_out = '".$time_out."' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: no changes is happening in database

Comment: if your post value of time in format is dd-mm-YYY then it works fine  if your date format is dd/mm/YYY  the you have to use this code date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(str_replace('/','-'$_POST['time_in'])));

Comment: AND is incorrect syntax in this context. It won't produce an error, but it's in effect saying 'SET time_in = 0'

Comment: this is what the time_in looks like in db 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: i want to know your input value of time_in and time_out

Comment: ah mate it was AND which was making this erro :) thanks for pointing it out now it works

Comment: @lalthung So don't accept an answer which perpetuates the error. Instead, answer the question yourself, and accept that.

Comment: @Strawberry i had no option to accept ur answer i only the the option on here

Comment: @lalthung You're mistaken.

Comment: i still cannot see any option to tick ur comment trust me i can show u a screen shot. i only had the user sunils comment to click